# Ocaml: add up all the integers in an int list and output it as an int Option

Tags: ocaml

. Write a function that takes an integer list and return sum of all elements of the list. If the list is empty then return None.

This is my code now:

```
let rec sum (xs: int list) =
   match xs with
   | [] -> None
   | [x] -> Some x
   | hd::tl -> let m = (hd + (sum tl)) in
                 Some m
;;
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to add up the last element without getting an error.
This is my error.
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a option.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive call to `sum` does indeed return an `int option`. You know this because you're the author of the function, and you coded it up to return that type :-) You can either write a helper function that returns an int, or you can extract the int from the return value of `sum`, something like this:

```
let tlsum =
    match sum tl with
    | None -> (* figure this part out *)
    | Some n -> (* figure this part out *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the addition of two int option.

```
let sum l =
  let (+) a b =
    match (a,b) with
      | (None,x) | (x,None) -> x
      | (Some x,Some y)     -> Some (x+y)
  in
  let convert a = Some a in
  let opt_l=List.map convert l  in
  List.fold_left (+) None opt_l
```

Test

```
# sum [];;
- : int option = None
# sum [1;2];;
- : int option = Some 3
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an assignment so I'll be vague:

The easiest way to do that is probably to first define a function of type `int list -> int` that returns the "normal" sum (with 0 for the empty case). That function will be recursive and `0` will correspond to the base case.

Then write another function of type `int list -> int option` that checks whether its argument is empty or not and does the right thing based on that.

Trying to write the recursion directly probably is not a good idea since there are two cases when you will need to handle `[]`: when it's the only element in the list, and when it's at the end of a nonempty list.